# Eigenvalues keep giving trivial solutions everytime.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of this Eigen BVP. $\mu$ is the eigenvalue parameter

$$
\lambda_h F''' - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h F'' + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) F' + \beta_h^2 F = 0
$$ wit BC(s) $F(0)=0,\frac{F''(0)}{F'(0)}=\beta_h,\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\beta_h$

For $\lambda_h=0.02$ and $\beta_h=10$, I calculated the EVs using *chebfun* in MATLAB. There are infinite number of negative EVs. The general solution should be of the form

$$
F(x) = \sum_k C_k e^{-\delta_k(\mu)x}
$$ 
Substituting the bc(s) yield three linear equations in $C_1,C_2,C_3$.
where $-\delta_k(\mu)$ are the three roots of the characteristic equation obtained after substituting one of the EVs.

But this keeps giving me trivial solutions i.e all $C_k=0$. I tried many EVs (ex. $-32.9463$)but to no avail.

Is there something horribly wrong in my understanding ? Is there some other approach i can apply to the problem ? I cannot figure out at all.

***ATTEMPT***

After @LutzL and @Christoph provided useful comments, i did some reading on null spaces of matrices and their use to solve the homogenous system of equations.

Using the EV mentioned above $-32.9463$ and $\lambda_h = 0.02, \beta_h = 10$, I arrive at three roots of the characteristic equation as:

$$
s_1 = 3.7421
$$
$$
s_2 = -11.8710+34.5722i
$$
$$
s_3 = -11.8710-34.5722i
$$

Now applying the three BC(s) i have the following matrix system $M(\mu).C_k=0$ and i need to find $C_k$ which will be the non trivial solutions. 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &  1 \\ 
{s_1}^2+\beta_hs_1 & {s_2}^2+\beta_hs_2 & {s_3}^2+\beta_hs_3 \\ 
e^{-s_1}({s_1}^2+\beta_hs_1) & e^{-s_2}({s_2}^2+\beta_hs_2) & e^{-s_3}({s_3}^2+\beta_hs_3) \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
C_1 \\ 
C_2 \\ 
C_3 \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}=0
$$
The  above is a homogeneous system of equations which i solved using the following command in MATLAB

```
[U,S,V] = svd(A,'econ');
b = V(:,size(A,2));
```

Here $A$ is the coefficient matrix. The solver `linsolve(A,B)` kept giving me trivial solutions. `svd` means singular value decomposition. `b` is supposed to be the solution we are looking for. For the parameters i mentioned here it comes out to be

```
b =-0.4550 + 0.0000i
    0.2278 + 0.5870i
    0.2278 - 0.5870i
```

It is mentioned that

> `b` will be a solution if the corresponding smallest singular value is zero.  If not, b will be the nearest you can come to a solution.  If more than one singular value is zero, there are infinitely many solutions of which this will be one

So the values of `b` must be my corresponding $C_1,C_2,C_3$. But they are coming out to be complex. So should i just take the magnitudes of these complex numbers to form my solution ?

Comment: Can't you get chebfun to compute the eigenfunctions as well?
Obviously $F \equiv 0$ is a solution to the BVP for any value of $\mu$. But since this cannot be an eigenfunction, your linear system $AC=0$ for the coefficients $C_1, C_2, C_3$ must have non-trivial solutions if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue. These are the solutions that you must find, for example by determining the null space of the linear map $C \mapsto AC$.

Comment: Set $C_3=1$ and leave out the last equation, the first two should then give numerical values for $C_1,C_2$. It is not surprising that you get an invertible if ill-conditioned matrix instead of a singular one if evaluated in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Christoph . Thanks. Yes i know that the system $AX=0$ do have $X=0$ as a trivial solution always and i must look for the non trivial solutions. Also, $chebfun$ does give something called eigenmodes which are plots. Your last point , says "determine the null space of the linear map C to AC . I am sorry to say, but i have no idea how this is done and how i should move forward with it.

Comment: @LutzL . If i understand you correctly, using just two bc(s) , taking $C_3=1$ i should calculate the values of $C_1,C_2$ . Then using these two numerical values of $C_1,C_2$ , i must calculate $C_3$ using the third equation from the third bc.

Comment: No, you get a linear space of eigenfunctions. There will always be a free parameter. The eigenvalue equation is to determine when *exactly* the three conditions will be linearly dependent. This means at most two are independent. The kernel space has at least dimension one. The solutions of this homogeneous problem form the kernel space.

Comment: @Lutzl really appreciate your effort. But i completley fail to understand the meaning or how i should proceed now. This may be amateurish. I am not trying to ask for a solution but rather a workflow for how i should proceed. Maybe you tried just that, but i could not comprehend it.

Comment: @LutzL I made an attempt following your suggestions. Have edited the original question . Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: @Christoph Made an attempt as you advised

Comment: Here you have complex conjugate $s_2 = \overline{s_3}$ and $C_2 = \overline{C_3}$. Therefore, the corresponding eigenfunction will be something like $F(x) = C_1 e^{-s_1 x} + 2 e^{-\mathrm{Re}(s_2) x} \left( \mathrm{Re}(C_2) \cos(\mathrm{Im}(s_2) x) + \mathrm{Im}(C_2) \sin(\mathrm{Im}(s_2) x) \right)$. $C_1$ should probably be zero here.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks a lot. I succeeded in building the eigen function for this EV. Now my only uncertainity is how many Eigenvalues i should use, is there something specific i must look into ?

Comment: Your characteristic roots have the wrong sign, if you set $y=ce^{-sx}$ for $0=a_3y'''+a_2y''+a_1y'+a_0y$, then the characteristic polynomial has to be $0=a_3s^3-a_2s^2+a_1s-a_0$.

Comment: @LutzL You were correct. I have edited my post to reflect the changes.

Comment: This is now looking good. My own results only differ in the 4th decimal and the plots of the bvp-solver solution and the sum of exponentials overlay each other correctly.

Comment: @LutzL Can you give some pointers on how may eigen values I should consider to build my final $F(x)$ solution ?